# Returning the salt value used in PHP's new password hashing API

Tags: php, passwords, salt

I'm currently implementing a webapp that leverages PHP's [new](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) (to be released as part of v5.5) password handling API. I think it's really good but I'm wondering if anyone knows why `password_get_info()` doesn't return the salt value used in the computation of the given hash? The [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) explicity states that the function in question doesn't return the salt, but no explanation as to why:

> The second element is “options”, which includes the used options by
>   the hashing algorithm, with the exception of the salt used.

The reason why I'm asking is because when a user's password expires, I need to check that they aren't resubmitting the same password as their current one. The only way to do this is to hash the new password, with the same algo, cost and salt compare the resulting hash to the one currently in the DB. The algo and cost are returned by the `password_get_info()` function but not the salt. At the moment, I use `substr($hash, 7, 22)` to get the salt value but this is obviously algorithm specific and kind of defeats the purpose of using an otherwise very easy to use and powerful API (if I start using a new algo the position of the salt may very well change).

EDIT: I was being an idiot, I didn't need to rebuild the hash and compare the resulting hashes but rather to call `password_verify()` and check that it returns `FALSE`. That'll teach me to work while sick and tired!

Comment: Not a php developer, but I do some crypto. Can you hash the new pw and compare the new hash to the old hash?  Also, re salts, I find a good practice is to not use a dedicated salt, but to salt using some other well known info, like the username.  That way, you always have a semi-unique salt that is stored right in the user account, and not taking up space as a separate column of data.

Comment: @NikMartin salts should be cryptographically strong.

Comment: @Hiroto - salts are never secrets, they just generate secrets. edit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography). Think of a salt as a public key. It can be random, but isn't required to be. They have to be known, and hence are not secret.

Comment: @NikMartin salts are not secret, i know that. they ***should*** however, be generated by a Cryptographically Secure Pseudo Random Number Generator, which I just said... (albeit informally)

Comment: @NikMartin this is to prevent the salt from being guessed, which is far more likely than you'd think with some of the computing power out there. Especially if it's generated using sources that are known (much like a non-CSPRNG's seed being known with little effort)

Comment: True, if someone know the scheme used to salt, they can easily use it in a rainbow table, but now they have to know or guess 2 pieces of info. vs one, making the time to do a rainbow exponentially longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, you don't need to know this information. Simply compare input to previous hashes (By this, i mean store a record of every hash a user has had and iterate through all of them, checking the result of `password_verify` against the new password input).
Bcrypt is useful like that; in fact, this is required behaviour of any algorithm that `password_hash` or `password_verify` will use, because otherwise you can't compare in the same way, and functionality changes.

```
password_verify(string $password, string $hash):
    $hash = crypt($plaintext, '$2y$' . $workrate . '$' . $salt)
    => $2y$<workrate>$<salt><hash> as result,
```

However, if you really need to find the salt of a bcrypt hash (which is what `password_hash` uses), then simply take the first 22 characters of the hash, minus the settings (But I will repeat, however, that you just need to compare input to hashes).

Ideally you should wrap `password_hash` inside of a class or function that can deal with dynamic workrates, and changing options (if the hash was saved as workrate 12, for example, you are able to use different workrates based on the age of the hash, and encourage users to update their passwords).

The functions don't return the salt because it's generated by a [CSPRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG), and isn't needed at all for comparison as a separate parameter (as it is part of the hash)

Comment: I'm not following here, all I have is the current hash and the new password, with no information on the actual password currently in use, what must I compare to what? Could you please explain what you mean by "simply compare input to previous hashes"? I mentioned in my question that I use substr at the moment to get the salt but that technique is flawed. Oh and password_hash is indeed only part of 5.5 onwards.

Comment: Oh, it just clicked! I don't need to go the long way round, just call password_verify() with the new password and check that it returns FALSE. Thanks....

Comment: @JonoCoetzee glad it helped. Ask a question and consider all answers; don't subconsciously answer it yourself (i.e. "I need the salt"). :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think my answer goes above currently accepted.

So why is `password_get_info()` does not return you a salt? This is because your salt is already stored in the hash. So when you are providing hast into the `password_verify` it can extract the salt.

Check it yourself:

```
password_hash('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, [
   'salt'  => 'mySaltShouldBeVeryLong
]);
```

The result looks like this: `"$2y$10$mySaltShouldBeVeryLonevYKGp78vooNv9Y7Kwy29CBdNLSUOutS"`. If you will look carefully, you will notice similarity with your salt. But it is not a good idea to provide your own salt (it is hard to make it unique). Because of this the algorithm will take care of generating its own salt. Because of this you can see that

```
password_hash('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT) !== 
password_hash('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

Hashes are completely different because different salt was used. This is done because average developer is not strong in security and do not know what is salt, pepper, collision and other cool words.

Use [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create hashes and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check if it is correct. Take a look at a cost parameter in password_hash().